# Catching close event of form from another form on Qt4

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have two forms, say form1 and form2, now I want to catch close event of form2 when closed in form1.

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: @Mat "want to catch close event of form2 when closed in form1", I just didn't figure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What about reimplementing [void QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent * event)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qwidget.html#closeEvent) in class of Form2 and emitting a signal from the reimplemented function. You could connect this signal to a slot of Form1. Something like this:

```
void Form2::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event)
{
    emit closeRequestHasArrived();
    QWidget::closeEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Seems like [finished](http://www.doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/en/4.7.x/qdialog.html#finished) signal do what I need, thanks for suggestions.